# integrating cc.net with uppercut

Tags: .net, cruisecontrol.net

I installed uppercut in my system successfully,
Then i installed cc.net,
for automated build revision number,
I followed all the steps in the following site,
http://ferventcoder.com/archive/2009/05/21/uppercut---automated-builds---cruisecontrol.net-integration.aspx

The same config code in that site i used to integrate
but still i could find the following error when i run the cc.net

svn folder Unable to execute file [D:\CodeBuild\abc\svn]. The file may not exist or may not be executable. --->  System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified..

Is there any different procedure to install cc.net?? I just run the exe and it said set virtual memory manually,

When does the build and revision number increase??

Please help me.........
I m n trouble

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It expects subversion to be on the command line. It's one of the requirements of UppercuT, that you can open a command line and type svn and have it execute subversion commands. In other words, that svn is on the PATH.